# PyCharm set pattern for newly created file

Tags: python, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Every time when I create `.py` file in django project, I need to add two strings

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Is there any way to set some pattern for newly created python files in PyCharm?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/creating-and-editing-file-templates.html Is something like this what you're looking for?

Comment: I think pycharm cannot do it. it comes with django version I think

Comment: @Harrison yes, you was right. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File->settings->Editor->File and Code Templates->Python Script

[image]